# MongoDB with Authentication

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get MongoDB running on my localhost (Windows) with authentication.

To do so, I first have to add a user, right?
I did so by starting the daemon using this command:

```
C:\[…]\mongod.exe -f C:\[…]\mongo.config
```

mongo.config contains the following:

```
# Basic database configuration
dbpath = C:\[…]\db\
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 20571

# Security
noauth = true

# Administration & Monitoring
nohttpinterface = true
```

After that I connected via this command:

```
C:\[…]\mongo.exe --port 20571 127.0.0.1
```

There I added a user:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.addUser('test', 'test')
{ "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 1, "err" : null, "ok" : 1 }
{
    "user" : "test",
    "readOnly" : false,
    "pwd" : "a6de521abefc2fed4f5876855a3484f5",
    "_id" : ObjectId("50db155e157524b3d2195278")
}
```

To check if everything worked I did the following:

```
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50db155e157524b3d2195278"), "user" : "test", "readOnly" : false, "pwd" : "a6de521abefc2fed4f5876855a3484f5" }
```

Which seemed OK to me.

After that I changed "noauth = true" to "auth = true" in the mongo.config file and restarted the daemon.

Now I expected to be able to connect with user and password:

```
C:\[…]\mongo.exe --port 20571 -u test -p test 127.0.0.1
```

Which denied access to me with this message:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:20571/127.0.0.1
Wed Dec 26 16:24:36 uncaught exception: error { "$err" : "bad or malformed command request?", "code" : 13530 }
exception: login failed
```

So here's my question: **Why does the login fail?**

I can still connect without providing user and password, but can't access any data because "unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1". Which is actually what I expected.

Comment: --host 127.0.0.1 instead of plain 127.0.0.1 or don't specify the host part, since mongo will connect to localhost by default

Comment: `C:\[…]\mongo.exe --port 20571 -u test -p test --host 127.0.0.1` gets me another error: `MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:20571/test
Thu Dec 27 14:07:06 uncaught exception: login failed
exception: login failed`

Comment: try doing: `use admin ` `db.auth('test','test')`, additionally to the db.addUser(...) because you added the user, but not giving any auth privileges

Comment: restarted db with `auth = false`, executed what you suggested, restarted with `auth = true`, can't connect. Same error as in my comment above.

Comment: try doing: `use test` and then `db.addUser('test',test)` and restart the mongo instance and try to connect to it with `--auth`

Comment: Have you tried with `.\mongo.exe admin --port […]`?

Comment: Andrei Sfat, that worked. Lambda Dusk, no I haven't tried that.

Comment: @Dave mongo users are per database. As far as I can see you made one for `admin`, so it can only login to that one.

Comment: That hint was essential for me to understand what was going on there. If you posted an answer I would love to give you some reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrei Sfat told me in the comments on the question I made 2 major errors.

First, I thought I could pass the IP to the Client as a simple argument. But you have to use --host for that.
Instead, the parameter I thought was the IP address actually should be the db name.
So the correct command to connect to a Server is as follows:

```
C:\[…]\mongo.exe --port 20571 -u test -p test --host 127.0.0.1 admin
```

Second, users are per database. As I only added the user "test" to the db "admin", it only works there.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the `auth = true` configuration wasn't load successfully. Did you forget the -f paramter when you restart the mongod.exe?

```
C:\[…]\mongod.exe -f C:\[…]\mongo.config
```

Comment: The configuration was loaded successfully. See comments under my question. Sorry for not marking it as solved.